# MySQL Select when not exist return 1

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariasql

I have a problem in the MySQL Query:

How can i SELECT something but when it errors because it doesn´t exist it should return a value like 1 or something else.

My Query

```
SELECT License FROM fivem_auth WHERE IP = '34.45.34.77';
```

Comment: Can there be multiple rows and you need to return all of them if they exist?

Comment: That query cannot error. It will just return 0 rows. It's not really clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `UNION` your query with a query that returns the default if the row doesn't exist.

```
SELECT License FROM fivem_auth WHERE IP = '34.45.34.77'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM fivem_auth WHERE IP = '34.45.34.77')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no error when a row doesn't exist.  It simply returns no rows.  If you are expecting one value, here are two methods that return `NULL` instead:

```
SELECT (SELECT License FROM fivem_auth WHERE IP = '34.45.34.77') as Licence;

SELECT MAX(License)
FROM fivem_auth
WHERE IP = '34.45.34.77';
```

For either of these, you can use `COALESCE()` to returns a non-`NULL` value.  But `NULL` seems appropriate for no value in the table.

Answer (score 0):

If `IP` is unique and you expect just 1 row in the results, use aggregation which will always return a row even when the condition fails and in that case `COALESCE()` will return `1`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(License), '1') 
FROM fivem_auth 
WHERE IP = '34.45.34.77';
```